# Show Mail Control Panel item from Outlook 2010 (32-bit)on Windows 2008R2 Terminal Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, terminal-server, outlook-2010

I try to show the Mail Control Panel item in Windows 2008 R2. I only type the Name "Mail" in to the "Show only specified Contol Panel items Properties" in the Group Policy.

In Windows 2008 R2 that doesn't work and theres no item in the Control Panel to configure Outlook 2010 Profiles. I already tried with: Mail and Mail(32-bit).

I didn't find the suitable entry on on the side: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330741%28VS.85%29.aspx#

Kind regards
Mischa

Comment: Is Outlook actually installed on the server?

Comment: Yes, Outlook is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been having the same issue, after doing some searching on the web I found the solution,
You need to add the following to the allowed list:

mlcfg32.cfg

This is the page that I found:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Control_Panel_applets

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have Server 2008R2 and I apply the GPO on windows 7 32 bit with office 2010 32 bit.

and this is work's for me

mlcfg32.cpl

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330741(v=vs.85).aspx

I hope it's will help for everyone.

Avraham.